# Registered Apps is not showing. How do I find it?

Tags: google-oauth

I'm following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php

The first three parts of step 1 are fine, but I cannot complete the 4th part because I cannot see "Registered Apps" in the sidebar on the left.

Step 1: Enable the Google+ API

Create a Google APIs Console project, OAuth 2.0 client ID, and register your JavaScript origins:

To register a new application, do the following:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select a project, or create a new one.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure the Google+ API status is set to ON.
4. In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has not been updated for the newer Console.
IIRC, you can simply skip this step - check if is works for you this way.
Or try older Console, it still works: https://code.google.com/apis/console/